# How does this circuit even work?

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis

[image]

An LT-spice simulation suggests that the output is always near -15V, that is, saturation. Assuming linearity, I come up with only two linearly independent equations:   $$I_{in}=\frac{Vin}{R}$$
$$I_{R3}=\frac{-Vout}{R3}$$

Comment: Is the bottom side of R2 at -15 V ? R2 is not in your equations.

Comment: That circuit is a mess.  If you saw this somewhere, explain the context, and be sure that you copied it right.  Otherwise, if you dreamed this up in some hallucigen-induced stupor, forget about it and move on.  Also keep in mind that simulators aren't designed to model parts correctly when used way off spec.  In fact, real parts aren't predictable either when used way off spec.

Comment: @OlinLathrop This is an exercise in my analogue electronics course. Obviously, it's just there to test our knowledge on this very subject.

Comment: @FakeMoustache  All I can see is that the bottom of  R2 is at some voltage we presume to be the positive supply voltage.

Comment: If this is a exercise from a book, then I think you miscopied something.  Perhaps show a scan of the schematic in the book.  For example, is the positive power pin of the opamp really connected to -15V?  Is the negative supply terminal really not connected to a supply or to ground?  As it is, your schematic is really screwed up.

Comment: If the purpose of the circuit is to burn out op-amp chips, it will work a treat since the +supply is connected to -15 and the non-inverting input is grounded. Please provide a scan of the circuit as shown in the book and/or correct your schematic above.

Comment: Did you know ! **Simulators cannot be trusted** !!! Before hitting that "simulate" button, think a moment about what you expect. Then when you do not see what you expect, try to determine who is wrong, you, or the simulator ? Or both ? Never trust your simulator because it **will** fool you ! Trust me, I have been dealing with simulators for 25 years.

Comment: I edited the question. Note that is is supposed the negative supply voltage is still there, but not included as to save space.

Comment: It is still unclear to me what pins 1, 4, 5 and 7 do. For any pins on Opamps other than inputs (marked + and -) and the output, clearly mark what pins these are for. Offset ? Bias setting ? Output enable ? Supply rails ??

Comment: You guys do realize that I am as puzzled as you are? But, let's assume that we are not using the pins for offset correction,etc. only the supply rails, and the inverting  and non inverting input.

Comment: What text book is this example circuit out of?

Comment: @Tyler Durden. None in particular, it was taken from a previous year's test.

Comment: @Shemafied: As long as you don't tell what pins 1, 4, 5 and 7 are supposed to be (see comment of FakeMoustache) there is no point in giving any answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will make the following assumptions: pin 7 is the positive supply, and is connected to a positive supply V+ (but assumed, not shown), and pin 4 is connected to a negative supply V- (again, assumed but not shown.)

Then the two left-hand resistors provide a 1:1 divider to V+. To bring the - input to ground, current must balance, and $$\frac{V_{IN}}{R} + \frac{V+}{R} + \frac{V_{OUT}}{R} = 0$$ and since the R's drop out$$V_{OUT}= -(V_{OUT} + V+)$$